# Cascading updates through composite primary keys in Mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

Cascading an update through a composite foreign key to another foreign key works in Postgres but not in Mariadb. How come and is there a good work around?

[A picture of the setup. The SKU table generates the SKU by concatenating the corresponding digits based on the compound specific properties stored in referenced tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWoyR.png)

Best shown through an example:
Mariadb: https://dbfiddle.uk/hLtpBb6C
Postgres: https://dbfiddle.uk/jBWfRqYi

Comment: The manual says 'do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html and if you follow this (ie comment out one of the FKs in table3) then no error occurs in mysql or mariadb - as to why that's a question for the mysql/mariadb team.

Comment: Code written in one sql dialect is rarely transportable to another except at the most basic level.